# Hibernate Criteria Query with Group By and aliasToBean

Tags: java, hibernate

I have table /entity called SaleRecord with fields such as

```
@Entity
public class SaleRecord {
   private Long id;
   private String type;
   private Double amount;
   //Getter and Setter and more fields
}
```

I want to write below query using Criteria

```
SELECT s.type AS accountName, SUM(s.amount) AS amount 
FROM salerecord s
GROUP BY s.type
```

I have written using plain SQL in Hibernate as (Its working)

```
String sql = " SELECT s.type AS accountName, SUM(s.amount) AS amount ";
            sql += " FROM salerecord s ";
            sql += " GROUP BY s.type ";

List<CollectionDO> incomeList = (List<CollectionDO>) getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CollectionDO.class)).list();
```

CollectionDO is another POJO class in which I want to populate the result.

But want to write using criteria, So how to write this query and transform result into CollectionDO class.
I have tried following but not working

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(SaleRecord.class).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CollectionDO.class));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("type"));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.sum("amount"));        
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("type"));
        return (List<CollectionDO>) criteria.list();
```

**CollectionDO.java**

```
public class CollectionDO {    
    private Double amount;    
    private String accountName;

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }
    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }
    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }     
}
```

Comment: what does it mean by not working? Throwing some error?

Comment: No. There is no exception, but result list in null. I think it is not able to Transform. as in Criteria column name is "type" but CollectionDO.java has field as "accountName"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I think it is not able to Transform. as in Criteria column name is "type" but CollectionDO.java has field as "accountName"

Try it as follows (using this version of [add](http://www.163jsp.com/help/hibernate32api/org/hibernate/criterion/ProjectionList.html#add%28org.hibernate.criterion.Projection,%20java.lang.String%29) to specify the alias name):

```
Criteria criteria = 
    getSession()
        .createCriteria(SaleRecord.class)
        .add(Restrictions.between("date", 
                                  reportForm.getFromDate(), 
                                  reportForm.getToDate()));

        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("type"), "accountName")
            .add(Projections.sum("amount"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("type")));
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CollectionDO.class))
return (List<CollectionDO>) criteria.list();
```

Comment: I think it is returning result but as Objects and not as CollectionDO objects. So while iterating it is throwing exception as java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.commission.controller.dashboard.CollectionDO

Comment: The same thing works for me except that I call the setResultTransformer after the call to setProjection, in a similar situation in my code. Do you want to give that a try once?

Comment: I updated my answer as to how exactly I was adding projections and transformer class in my code. Not sure if you got a chance to see that.